# Why are my data saved in WebSQL and not in IndexedDB? (ionic)

Tags: ionic-framework, storage, indexeddb, web-sql

I can't understand this simply thing. I need to store data in a database so, following the ionic documentation, I did exactly what this page says:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

I read on web that WebSQL is deprecated so I'd like to use IndexedDB to store data. The problem is that using get/set methods and running "ionic serve" I see that data is stored in WebSQL (in the form of a string, so difficult to see objects like in IndexedDB).

What am I doing wrong? How to store in IndexedDB and why prefer it to WebSQL?

Answer (score 1):

From the Docs

> Configuring Storage
>
> The Storage engine can be configured both with specific storage engine priorities, or custom configuration options to pass to localForage. See the localForage config docs for possible options: https://github.com/localForage/localForage#configuration

You have to pass the order correctly.

```
IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
  name: '__mydb',
     driverOrder: ['indexeddb', 'sqlite', 'websql']
})
```

if so delete `sqlite` and `websql` and try again

Comment: The link is about "forage" (and I don't know what it is). In fact if I write that code deleting `sqlite` and `websql`, I get the error `Error: No available storage method found.`

Comment: forage is the StorageEngine that is used by ionicStorage. The Quote is from the page you are linked to https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/.
When you get the above error indexdb is not available so IonicStorage is switching to websql to store the data

Comment: So is there a way to make IndexedDB available?

Comment: @AlessioF Maybe you have already worked it out, but just in case somebody comes across your post and wants to set up an indexed db web app: use Dexie: http://dexie.org/. I can't understand why they made Indexed DB such a nightmare to use, dexie is a very intuituve layer which makes your life much easier. I am aware of other projects which do the same, but I haven't tried them.

Comment: @AlessioF There is an issue is in the chrome dev tools. The predefined iPhone sizes in the size selection don't support indexeddb as a storage. In that case Ionic Storage/ localForage is falling back to use websql. Switching between sizes like responsive <> iPhone can also lead to duplicate storage entries, because of the fallback. See also my comment on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369826/ionic-storage-unwanted-changing .

Answer (score 1):

it is really easy just :
add ‘localstorage’ to driverOrder
like this::

```
IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
  name: “Database”,
  driverOrder: [“indexeddb”, “localstorage”]
}),
```