# Ionic Storage unwanted changing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm having problems with the Ionic Storage.

When I log into my app, its saved on storage some configuration objects.
On my last check was on IndexedDb.

But if I save any file changes or simply refresh the page, sometimes it switches from IndexedDb to Web SQL...

All my data is "lost" because the DB is a fresh new one.

Anyone knows why its happening or how to solve.

This is my **app.module** storage settings

```
IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
    name: '__cds',
    driverOrder: ['indexeddb', 'sqlite', 'websql']
})
```

I'm afraid the repercussions on this when I compiled into an App.
So far I'm only on browser develop

**That's how I set it**

//response is an object I'm receiving from http call

```
this.storage.set('cds', response).then(() => {
    this.goHome();
});
```

**That's how I get it**

```
this.storage.get('cds').then(cds => {
    this.variable = JSON.parse(cds);
});
```

[image]

See, it's not "mantaining" the storage on a single db

Comment: It could be helpful if you supply the code for accessing the storage and creation of the storage.

Comment: @Malcor in a minute buddy!

Comment: Does this happen in other browsers?

Comment: @Malcor didn't tested, but it doesn't matter that much cause this thing will be a problem on mobile... Do you have any idea on whats the problem?

Comment: So you have tested on a mobile and it still has the same problem? I'm trying to work out if this is a bug with the browser you're using or an unknown side effect.

Comment: @Malcor I discovered. and I think its a default "feature" of Chrome. I'll put as an anwer. thanks for your help man!! :D

Comment: If you're using chrome, when in dev mode, check your `network` tab, see if `cache` is disable or not. if It's disabled it might be wiping your localstorage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out the problem is a "feature" (I think) of Chrome Web Dev Tools. 
You see, when I refresh the app I was using the **Toggle Device Toolbar**

[image]

This helps the web design. If you notice this one is marked as **Responsive**

For a lot of other reasons, I suddenly changed my tab to one of **Iphone** size

[image]

I don't know why it works like this, but this little change make more than just alter the viewport size...

The storage base in use changed as well, and my problem begun.

**In terms of a production App this will not be a problem**, as I think the user was not able to "switch" viewport sizes on Chrome Dev Tools....

That's it. Thanks Marcol for your help!!

Comment: This problem still exists in December 2020! Even clearing the site data via dev tools doesn't resolve the issue. It looks like that indexeddb can't be used when one of the predefined iPhones sizes is selected. 

Selected device iPhone: (ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No available storage method found.
Error: No available storage method found.)

So when you start with any other size then one of the iPhone ones, you're using indexeddb and when you then switch to the iPhone sizes localForage is switching to webSQL/sql, based on the config. At this point your storage is messed up.

Comment: As of March 10, 2021 this is still an issue with Google Chrome.  I was getting the above errors and unexpected behavior.  Of course, I thought the problem was in my code but alas, it wasn't.  I  hope other people journey to this answer isn't as fraught with frustration as mine was!