# Ionic 3 : storage in both IndexedDB and Web SQL

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, indexeddb, web-sql

I'm working on a mobile application for both android and iOS mobile phone.

I'm experiencing something very weird with the Storage. I get data in both IndexedDB and Web SQL (when I'm testing/debugging in Browser).

Here is the declaration of the module :

```
IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
```

I have troubble because when I tried to get data from Storage I get data from Web SQL (which contains old values...) and not from IndexedDB where I have the latest values.

I would like so to set a prefered order like this :

```
IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
    name: '__myprojectdb',
    driverOrder: ['indexeddb']
})
```

But, should it work correctly on both iOS and Android? Are there any requirements or prefered DB type depending on devices?

I'm open to ideas ! As I'm new in Ionic and mobile application.

Thanks in advance for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

The storage that is used depends on which mode you're using the "inspect->preview" of Chrome with Ionic. [You can find more info in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369826/ionic-storage-unwanted-changing)