# set storage of an object of arrays in Ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, storage, ionic-storage, cordova-sqlite-storage

I have an ionic 5 app to be build for browser.  I have installed @ionic/Storage, etc.  I have a function in my service the current iteration is as follows:

```
async setStorageObj( key: string, values: any) {
console.log(key, values);
return this.storageCtrl.set( key, values );
```

}

*"key"* is a single string *"product attributes"* and values is an object of arrays(I think).  It looks like this in the developer console:
*Product Attributes:
[sportsdemo_x_xxx: [{key:value pairs}, {key:value pairs}, {key:value pairs}],
sportsdemo_y_yyyyy: [{key:value pairs}, {key:value pairs}], ...etc]*

The console log above shows correct in the console so I know the values are there.  However the its showing up in storage as *"ProductAttributes: []*.  I am simply unable to figure out the correct syntax.
I've been at it for a awhile and its late... maybe I am just tired.  Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: HELP https://stackoverflow.com/q/66511336/14826914

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with two solution to this question:

1. loop through the object of arrays and set each array

   ```
   for (k in object) { 
      this.storageCtrl.set (k, object(k)); }
   ```

or

2. the solution I went with:

   ```
   async setStorageObj( values: any[]) {
       return await this.storageCtrl.set("productAttributes", JSON.stringify(values));
   }
   ```

Comment: As it turns out, there was nothing wrong with my code.  I was getting unexpected behavior because of a problem with goggle chrome dev tools app preview size being set to iPhone X.  Apparently there is a bug that causes all kinds of unexpected behavior.  See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369826/ionic-storage-unwanted-changing