# ionic upload file / capacitor / file path / readasArrayBuffer

Tags: ionic-framework

HELP :Ionic /i'm trying to upload files to firebase but i can't read the  content  of the file help [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDzOc.png)

Comment: code is helpful

Comment: ok i add the code : home.page.ts and serviceFirebase.ts

Comment: i think there is a problem in ReadasArrayBuffer, it's still running without any results            const buffer = await this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(this.filePath, this.fileName);

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { File} from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { FileChooser } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser/ngx';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path/ngx';
import { FireBaseService } from 'src/app/services/firebase-service.service';
import { Plugins, FilesystemDirectory, FilesystemEncoding } from '@capacitor/core';

const { Filesystem } = Plugins;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],

})
export class HomePage {

 fileforSending ;
 fileUri  :string;
 filePath :string;
 fileName :string;
 fileType :string;
 entry;

  constructor(
    private fireService:FireBaseService,
    private fileChooser:FileChooser,
    private file :File,
    private pathConverter :FilePath) {
  }
  
  choose(){
    this.fileChooser.open()
    .then(uri => {
      //getting URI of a choosen file
      this.fileUri = uri;
      return this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(this.fileUri);

    }).then(fileEntry => {
      this.entry = fileEntry;
      this.entry.file((arg) => {
        //getting mime type of a file
        this.fileType = arg.type;
      })

    }).then(() => {
      return this.pathConverter.resolveNativePath(this.fileUri)

    }).then((filePath) => {
      //converting file URI to normal file PATH & file NAME
      this.filePath = filePath.substring(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/'));
      this.fileName = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('/'), filePath.length).replace("/", "");

    }).then(async () => {
      try {
        const buffer = await this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(this.filePath, this.fileName);
        await this.fireService.uploadFileToStorage(buffer, this.fileType, this.fileName);
      } catch (error) {
        alert(`Buffering failed ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
      } finally {
        alert('finally');
      }
       }).catch(err =>  {console.log('error: ', err) });
}
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

--------------------------firebase service-----------------------
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireStorage} from "@angular/fire/storage";

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FireBaseService {
    
  constructor(private af: AngularFireStorage){}

  
  async uploadFileToStorage(file, type, name) {
      const randomId = Math.random()
          .toString(36)
          .substring(2, 8);

      let oMyBlob = new Blob([file], {type : type})
       const uploadTask = this.af.upload(`files/${new Date().getTime()}_${randomId}_${name}`,oMyBlob);
        console.log('upload task '+uploadTask)
        uploadTask.then(async res => {
        console.log('file upload finished!');
      }).catch(err =>  {
          console.log('file wasnt upload. Error: ' + err);
      });
  }
}

export { FireBaseService as ExportedClass };
```

Answer (score 0):

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from "@angular/fire/database";

import {AngularFireStorage} from "@angular/fire/storage";

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FireBaseService {

```
constructor(private af: AngularFireStorage){}

async uploadFileToStorage(file, type, name) {
    const randomId = Math.random()
        .toString(36)
        .substring(2, 8);

    let oMyBlob = new Blob([file], {type : type})
    
    const uploadTask = this.af.upload(
        `files/${new Date().getTime()}_${randomId}_${name}`,
        oMyBlob
    );

    uploadTask.then(async res => {
        console.log('file upload finished!');
    }).catch(err =>  {
        console.log('file wasnt upload. Error: ' + err);
    });
}
```

}

export { FireBaseService as ExportedClass };